# negative dimension size error while training CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm facing an error while training my CNN model in Keras. The error message states:

> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node
> sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC",
> dilations=, explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=,
> use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](sequential/max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool,
> sequential/conv2d_2/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes:
> [?,1,1,64], [3,3,64,128].

Code:

```py
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense

model2 = Sequential()

# Convolutional Layers
model2.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model2.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model2.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2),padding='same'))
model2.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, strides=(2,2), activation='relu'))
model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2),padding='same'))

# Flatten Layer
model2.add(Flatten())

# Dense Layers
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model2.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))


# Final Classification Layer
model2.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the Model
#model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model2.compile( loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=0, patience = 5 )
history = model2.fit(scaled_images_train, targets_train, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=64, callbacks=[es])
```

initial data shape :

- images_train.shape (16500, 28, 28)
- targets_train.shape (16500,)
- images_test.shape (5445, 28, 28)
- targets_test.shape (5445,)
- Classes: ['The Eiffel Tower', 'book', 'car', 'airplane (1)', 'airplane', 'dog', 'apple', 'eye', 'brain', 'face', 'chair']

I have attempted to address the problem by adjusting the model structure and adding padding but have not been successful.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Assuming you want to keep your architecture the same, you could also add padding in the `Conv2D` blocks - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#args